# Using Lua debug to step-by-step execute

Tags: debugging, lua

Is there a way of using some type of debug to execute the Lua code step-by-step? Using only Lua commands or applications written in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZeroBrane](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) is written in Lua, and it has rather nice debugging facilities.

I don't get how "being written in Lua" has to do anything about it, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in bare-bones command-line debugger [`debug.debug()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.debug).

See also the [debug interface](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.9).